# Angular Providers

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-providers

Following the angular 2 tutorial @ https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html

In the

```
@Component({
})
```

I inserted "`providers: [HeroService]`" which contains the `getHeroes()` method.

Created a constructor:

```
constructor(private heroService: HeroService) {}
```

**Now the part I don't understand is how I am able to use**

`this.heroService.getHeroes()`

The only propertes defined in this class are:

```
title = 'Tour of Heroes';
heroes: Hero[];
selectedHero: Hero;
```

**Does the providers in the `@Component` decorator automatically create a property to access it through `this.`?**

The App is working, just don't know how we magically were able to access heroService through `this.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `private` (could also be `public`) in

```
constructor(private heroService: HeroService) {}
```

also creates a property `heroService` and assigns the value passed to the constructor. That's a TypeScript feature and is not Angular2 or DI dependent.

Comment: Interesting, so if I leave it blank, it defaults to public, but does not create a property, but the fact that you declare it as private or public will tell the class to create the property.

Good to know. I can't wrap my head around _why_ this syntax should have anything to do with creating a property. Is it because by defining it as private or public, means that you are implying it will be reused?

Sorry if this question doesn't make sense, I am fairly novice.

But either way, thank you for the answer. Very good to know ;)

Comment: It's very common to assign constructor parameters to properties, therefore they created this syntactic shugar. If you omit `private` and `public` no property is created and the `heroService` exists only within the constructor.